# Is it necessary for a unique key to be a uuid in Solr?

Tags: solr, full-text-search

Can a unique key in Solr/Lucene schema be `text_general` instead? I have tried that but Solr doesn't overwrite the data, it simply adds another row hence duplicating the data.

I have commented out following from `solrconfig.xml`

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
<!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
<str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
<str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>
```

My `schema.xml` has

```
<uniqueKey>_id</uniqueKey>
<field name="_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I know if my answer was helpful?

Comment: I didn't have time to test what you have provided, I am sure I will when I come back to search on my project. Meanwhile marking this as the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever type you want for the [`uniqueKey`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field) field. As you can read from the documentation:

> The  declaration can be used to inform Solr that there is a
>   field in your index which should be unique for all documents. If a
>   document is added that contains the same value for this field as an
>   existing document, the old document will be deleted.
>
> It is not mandatory for a schema to have a uniqueKey field.
>
> Note that if you have enabled the QueryElevationComponent in
>   solrconfig.xml it requires the schema to have a uniqueKey of type
>   StrField. It cannot be, for example, an int field.

What's important is that your uniqueKey field is unique, meaning that the same document has the same identifier. Only that way the *replace if existing* mechanism can work. Using an [uuid](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey#UUID_techniques) field type you'd never replace a document because you would have a different id for each one, automatically.